# Pseudo-classes are not loaded in react?

Tags: sass

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  sidebarList: {
    transition: 'width 0.2s ease',
    marginRight: '0px',
    width: '300px',
    '& > div': {
      width: 'inherit',
      marginTop: '100px',
      backgroundColor: '#212121',
      borderRight: 'none'
    },
    '&.mini': {
      transition: 'width 0.2s ease',
      width: '0px',
      '& > div': {
        width: 'inherit'
      }
    }
  },
  linkItem: {
    textDecoration: 'none',
    '&:focus': {
      outline: 'none'
    }
  },
  listItemIcon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  listItemText: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(1.5),
    '&:first-child': {
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(5)
    }
  }
}));

export default useStyles;
```

pseudo-classes are not displayed

```
'& > div': {
      width: 'inherit',
      marginTop: '100px',
      backgroundColor: '#212121',
      borderRight: 'none'
```

can you tell me how to fix it?

```
    import useStyles from 'components/Sidebar/styles';
    
    function MenuItem(props) {
      const { title } = props;
      return <Typography variant="body2">{title}</Typography>;
    }
    
    MenuItem.propTypes = {
      title: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };
    
    function SidebarItem(props) {
      const { link, inset, toggleSidebar } = props;
      const classes = useStyles();
    
      function handleItemClick() {
        if (isMobileDevice()) {
          toggleSidebar();
        }
      }
    
      return (
        <Link to={link.path} className={classes.linkItem} tabIndex="-1">
          <ListItem button onClick={handleItemClick}>
            {link.icon && <ListItemIcon className={classes.listItemIcon}>{link.icon}</ListItemIcon>}
            <ListItemText className={classes.listItemText} inset={inset} primary={link.title} />
          </ListItem>
        </Link>
      );
    }
    
    SidebarItem.propTypes = {
      link: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      inset: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      toggleSidebar: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };
    
    export default SidebarItem;
```

*applies to this file*

I did not write the imports part:

```
    import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { Link } from '@reach/router';
import { isMobileDevice } from 'tools/mobileCheck.js';
```

What am I doing wrong? Tell me please.
I don't know what else to write)) but it's not enough for them.
Thank you, if you need more information, write to me.

```
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(1.5),
    '&:first-child': {
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(5)
    }
  }
```

All pseudo-classes do not work((

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of pseudo-classes directly within the generated CSS is not supported by the makeStyles function, which is the problem. You can get around this restriction by using the &$pseudoClassName syntax.

Here's an example of how you can modify your styles to make the pseudo-classes work:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  sidebarList: {
    // Other styles...
    '& > div': {
      // Other styles...
      '&$mini': { // Use &$mini instead of &.mini
        // Mini styles...
      }
    }
  },
  mini: {}, // Define the mini class
  // Other styles...
}));
```

> Refer to [Docs](https://mui.com/system/styles/advanced/#makestyles)